# Getting the Title Value of SP.UI.ModalDialog

Tags: modal-dialog

I have a modal window created and I am able to show the window perfectly. I have passed the title as parameter and was able to see in the modal window, but I cannot find the code behind for me to retrieve the value of the title. The value of this.Page.title is always "\r\n\t".

```
var options = {
  url: uploadUrl,
  title: documentType,
  autosize: true,
  allowMaximize: true,
  showClose: true
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to get title in code behind is to attach it as query-string to URL and retrive that query-string in code-behind

```
var options = {
url: uploadUrl+"?title="+mytitle,
title: documentType,
autosize: true,
allowMaximize: true,
showClose: true
};
```

in .CS

```
  string title = Request.QueryString["title"];
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to avoid this approach as I am trying to optimize my code. By theory, the title should be retrievable somehow. I am looking for an answer that may involves retrieving the info via jquery and assign it to a code-behind variable but I could not formulate how to reach this goal.